# Dividing polygon layer into multiple layers by values in attribute table column using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, export, error-000354

I have polygon layer with multiple types of area (forest, grass, and many more), and I´d like to divide this layer into many layers by the area type.

I´ve tried Split function but I receive an error 000354 - because the type of areas are in Czech and contain national characters.

Please does anybody know how to do this??

For example how to automatically rename the types of areas to valid form, or how to write an python script which creates this layer for each of the area type in with definition query  for layer?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: Can you write a query using the Czech characters? If so can you make a selection and use a calculator to rename. In version 10 I can still use VB script with "replace" but not sure if version 10.1 is python only...

Comment: The only part which seems not to be the same as the duplicate is the Czech part but an answer was accepted that makes no reference to it so it seems to be an aside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see this functionality in ArcGIS. However, there is a free Toolbox with a tool named "Split Layer By Attribute" at this link. 
[ArcGIS Resource Center](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=37AEB018-1422-2418-A036-CA6D9920F808)

Comment: It´s look like a solution, but there is a problem with Czech national characters (ěščřžýáíéúů) - this script ends with error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128).
I tried to change coding of file or add "coding header" # -*- coding: cp1250 -*-, but it still ends on the error.

Comment: The File Geodatabase (.gdb) and Personal Geodatabase (.mdb) are supposed to support Unicode. Have you tested either of these?